# "EVARELTO" - What does this mean?

Tags: wordplay, rebus

Can anyone tell me what this secret message is?

> EVARELTO

Try finding the secret message represented by these letters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

> "Broken Elevator" or "Elevator out of order".

Reasoning:

> The letters from the word "Elevator" are broken up and mixed.